# How can I test ios app i coded on Xamarin.Forms on Windows 10 using a real iPhone iOS device?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile

Currently i don’t have apple developer account. I am developing on Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. I also have a mac device. I installed xcode on this mac. I run simulators on windows by the help of this mac connection. But i want to test my app on real iphone. How can i do this ?

Comment: Apple developer account is `required` if you want to deploy the application to a real iPhone ,refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run your development app on iOS device unless you have an Apple developer account. After you create the account, you need to create provisioning certificates for the device, download them. Only then you can run it

Answer (score 1):

To be able to deploy on a physical iOS Device, you either need to have an Apple Developer Account or you can get a free provisioning profile from XCode (No Apple Developer Account required).

To get a free provisioning profile,

You have to (**on your Mac**):

1. Open XCode > Preferences and add your Apple ID in the *Accounts* section. You can then close the Preferences tab.
2. Create a new project and select *Single View App*. In the *Team* drop-down list, set it to the Apple Id you just added.
3. After the creation of the project, target your iOS device for building.
4. Open General > Identity and make sure the Bundle Identifier matches the one found in your info.plist directly from your Xamarin.iOS app.
5. Under *Signing*, select *Automatically manage signing* and select your Team.

You should now be able to see your provisioning profile when clicking the  symbol under *Signing* - *Provisoning Profile* and you can test the deployment by clicking the run button.

To deploy your app from **Visual Studio**:

1. Make sure your Visual Studio is paired to the Mac.
2. Connect your iOS Device **to the Mac**
3. Navigate to iOS Bundle Signing in *Your iOS Project* > *Properties*.
4. For Configuration, select Debug.
5. For Platform, select iPhone.
6. Select Manual Provisioning.
7. Select the provisioning profile and the signing identity created by XCode

You should now be able to run the app. (Don't forget to target your IPhone for Deployment)

For more info, visit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows)

Answer (score 0):

Plug your phone into your computer using a USB to Lightning connector. Click Trust on your phone. Click on the simulator on XCode and choose your phone name. Click build. You will get an error on your phone saying untrusted developer. Go to settings on your phone, click general then profiles. Click on  the only one there and click trust. Now you can open your app.

Comment: I am not writing and building project on XCode. I am developing project on Windows, on Visual Studio 2019. I use Xcode just for running simulator on windows in visual studio xamarin forms.

Comment: You still need to do the steps described here to be able to deploy to a device.

Comment: Ok but i am not developing on xcode, what is the meaning of building on xcode. I am developing and building on visualstudio.

Comment: when you go to use the simulator, instead of using a simulator, select your phone name when it is plugged into your computer.